# Passing Multiple Radio buttons value from Visual force page to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using Page block table on visual force page and each row has radio buttons , i want to pass the value of each selected radio button , from each row on visual force page to apex Controller class.

For Now i am getting only one Value of last Row , I need Each Value of selected radio Buttons.

```
Visual Force Page


    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SurveyQuestions}" var="sq">
        <apex:column value="{!sq.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!sq.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!sq.QuestionID__r.Question__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!sq.QuestionID__r.Id}" headerValue="Question ID"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="HiddenQuestion Id">
         <apex:inputHidden value="{!sq.QuestionID__r.Id}" id="HdnQuestionID"/> 
        </apex:column>  
        <apex:column headerValue="Question options">
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedAnswer}">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio> 
        </apex:column>   
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Apex Controller Class

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('yes','Yes')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('no','No')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Maybe','maybe')); 
    return options; 
}

public PageReference SubmitSurvey() {

    // Multiple Checkbox value Logic Goes Here

    if(selectedAnswer == 'yes'){

               //Inserting The Survey Result

               tblSurveyResult__c SurveyResult = new tblSurveyResult__c(
                      Name = selectedAnswer,
                      Answer__c = 1
                     );
               insert SurveyResult;


        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Survey Submitted Successfully'));

    } else if (selectedAnswer == 'no'){

        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,selectedAnswer));

    } else {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please Select Atleast one value'));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Adil found ans to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) here. This is the best option in your use case. I am adding some sample code taken from Salesforce docs.

```
public class wrapperClassController {

    //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects cContact 
    public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

    //This method uses a simple SOQL query to return a List of Contacts
    public List<cContact> getContacts() {
        if(contactList == null) {
            contactList = new List<cContact>();
            for(Contact c: [select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact limit 10]) {
                // As each contact is processed we create a new cContact object and add it to the contactList
                contactList.add(new cContact(c));
            }
        }
        return contactList;
    }


    public PageReference processSelected() {

                //We create a new list of Contacts that we be populated only with Contacts if they are selected
        List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

        //We will cycle through our list of cContacts and will check to see if the selected property is set to true, if it is we add the Contact to the selectedContacts list
        for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
            if(cCon.selected == true) {
                selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
            }
        }

        // Now we have our list of selected contacts and can perform any type of logic we want, sending emails, updating a field on the Contact, etc
        System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
        for(Contact con: selectedContacts) {
            system.debug(con);
        }
        contactList=null; // we need this line if we performed a write operation  because getContacts gets a fresh list now
        return null;
    }


    // This is our wrapper/container class. A container class is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Contact and a Boolean value
    public class cContact {
        public Contact con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        //This is the contructor method. When we create a new cContact object we pass a Contact that is set to the con property. We also set the selected value to false
        public cContact(Contact c) {
            con = c;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Visual force

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <!-- In our table we are displaying the cContact records -->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >
                    <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Now use this code as reference you will get all selected value in your code. You can replace the checkbox with inputradio. and it will solve your problem.