# delete multiple records from an object

Tags: apex, dml

I want to delete multiple records of an object...How should I do it.

```
public class del_acc 
{
   public List<String> sel_id{get;set;}
   set<id> sid = new set<id>();
   List<Account> accIdList = new List<Account>();
   public void deleteacc()
   {
      if(sel_id != '')
      {
        List<Account> acc = new List<Account>(id=sel_id);
        delete acc;
       }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Comment: yeah i am passing id in Account but its for only 1 record...

Comment: then pass multiple id or you don't know how to pass multiple Ids. In case use wrapper class.

Comment: yeah I dont know how to pass multiple id's ..:(

Comment: use wrapper class. This might help (Wrapper class)[http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/105762/11239]

Comment: @Anzar, could you please tell what does the variable sel_id  does on the page. It is a list of string, does it get populated with individual elements as account IDs or is my understanding completely wrong.  Thanks

Comment: If it is indeed a list of IDs, then we can cast it into sfdc IDs and then delete the corresponding accounts. If you agree that my understanding is right then we can proceed - awaiting your reply.

Comment: @Stygon you are right I want this..

Comment: @Anzar can't add answer due to question being on hold. Firstly convert sel_id into a set of string as "Set<String> sel_idSet = new Set<String>(); sel_idSet.addAll(sel_id );". This is because we don't want repeated IDs while deleting stuff.

Comment: Then convert the set of string to set of IDs as 
" Set<ID> IDsToDelete = (Set<ID>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(sel_idSet), Set<ID>.class); ".
Then query out all the accounts "WHERE id IN :IDsToDelete ". Delete the list of accounts returned in the query.
An answer would have looked much better on the yes, sorry.

Comment: @Anzar awesome. Glad I could help. Question is still on hold, cant post an answer though. :(

Comment: @Stygon no prob :)

Answer (score 1):

@Anzar to pass multiple ids in apex search about for each loop.

```
for (Account o : send your set of id's) {

    /* Code for account omitted */
}
```

Comment: Telling someone to Google a search term isn't exactly what I think of as answering their question. Also, please visit [Help] to better learn how our Forum operates. Asking to have your answer marked as "best" isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks from now onward's i will follow guidelines how to post comments      @crmprogdev